# Should I tell my referees that my application got rejected ? (I intend to re-apply)

Tags: graduate-school

I applied to a Masters program and unfortunately, I was rejected. 
I intend to re-apply to another school and another program by the end of April, and I haven't had the chance to find other referees. 
When I re-apply, should I simply email my previous referees and request for another reference letter? or should I email them now casually and update them that my application was rejected?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer may depend on the exact relationship you have with your referees. I would think that if they were willing to write you a reference letter in the first place, they are invested in you and your academic success enough to warrant an update on your graduate admissions status. I think if you just emailed them for a new letter, they may wonder why you're requesting more letters relatively late in the application cycle, or they may ask about the status of your past applications. In either case, it is likely that you will need to disclose your rejection, so perhaps disclosing it first is a better strategy.

Plus, this may be a good opportunity to solicit feedback from them on your past application so you can incorporate any feedback given into your April application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should email them now just as a matter of politeness. They took their time to write a reference letter and deserve to hear an update.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you failed and requesting letters again you must explain to them.

Sometimes they invested a huge amount of time in you and your letters, especially if they are personalized. If they did whatever they can, they will be really angry if you failed due to your own lax. You must make sure that your failure is reasonable and you deserve another chance.